# How can i get the all checked radio button on a button click in a listview

Tags: android

i have structure like this

TextView
radio1 radio2

TextView
radio1 radio2

TextView
radio1 radio2

i want to known how can i get the all checked radio button on a button click
i tried like this

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup rgp;
                RadioButton rbtn;
                for(int i =0;i<listView.getChildCount();i++){
                    View layout =  listView.getChildAt(i);
                      //int text =    layout.getChildAt(1).getId();
                  int text =  (((ViewGroup) layout).getChildAt(1)).getId();


                       rgp = (RadioGroup)findViewById(text); 

                         rbtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(rgp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+rbtn.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: use base adapter and customize its view

Comment: Refer this http://developerandro.blogspot.in/2013/09/listview-with-checkbox-android-example.html

Comment: @Giridharan   i have that in my code i want to known y it is showing only first value selected every time.

Comment: make a loop pass selected values in arraylist..Display it another activity..try this it will work i think

Comment: basically what i want is on a button click i want to save the value of all radio button in Db. i want every thing on button click.